# How do i set the value of a custom column via a LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, js, field-mapping

I am trying to set the value of an custom checkbox field for the cart component, so that it can be mapped over to Order and OrderSummary.

The mapping between cart, Order and OrderSummary seem to be already be covered based on this - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.b2b_b2c_comm_dev.meta/b2b_b2c_comm_dev/b2b_b2c_comm_import_export_carttoorder.htm

But how I do actually set the value of the customField for the cart object?

I have currently made an LWC component where I via checkbox determine what the value of the columns should be -  my problems is though I am not able to get the recordId of the card via  Wire - it comes out as undefined?

html:

```
<template>
    <label>
        Include
        <input type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} onchange={handleCheckboxChange} />
    </label>
</template>
```

js:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import updateInsuranceField from '@salesforce/apex/OrderController.updateInsuranceField';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = ['Order.Insurance__c'];

export default class OrderInsuranceCheckbox extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    isChecked = false;
    _checkedByDefault;
    _orderID


    @api
    get checkedByDefault() {
        return this._checkedByDefault;
    }
    
    set checkedByDefault(value) {
        this._checkedByDefault = value;
        this.checked = value;
    }

    @api
    get orderId() {
        return this._orderId;
    }
    
    set orderId(value) {
        this._orderId = value;
    }


    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    orderRecord;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.retrieveInsuranceValue();
    }

    retrieveInsuranceValue() {
        if (this.orderRecord.data) {
            this.isChecked = getFieldValue(this.orderRecord.data, 'Order.Insurance__c');
            console.error(this.isChecked);
        } else if (this.orderRecord.error) {
            console.error('Error fetching order record', this.orderRecord.error);
        }
    }

    handleCheckboxChange(event) {
        this.isChecked = event.target.checked;

        updateInsuranceField({ recordId: this.recordId, includeInsurance: this.isChecked })
            .then(result => {
                console.error(this.recordId);
                console.error(this.isChecked);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Handle error if needed
                console.error(this.recordId);
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
}
```

OrderController.cls

```
public with sharing class OrderController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateInsuranceField(Id recordId, Boolean includeInsurance) {
        // Query the Order record
        Order orderToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Insurance__c FROM Order WHERE Id = :recordId LIMIT 1];

        // Check if the query returned any records
        if (orderToUpdate != null) {
            // Update the field and perform any other necessary logic
            orderToUpdate.Insurance__c = includeInsurance;
            update orderToUpdate;
        } else {
            // Handle the case where no records were found
            System.debug('No records found for Order with ID: ' + recordId);
            // You might want to throw a custom exception or log the issue
        }
    }


    public class OrderInfoWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Id Id { get; set; }
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean Insurance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this? a record page component? a flow screen component? How are you setting recordId?

Comment: @NickCook not sure I understand the this part`?
this component is just a component, supposed to put into a page. 
The state of the checkbox, has to be mapped to the insurance property of cart. 

Which then by the CartToOrder action automatically gets mapped to the other objects Order and OrderSummary.

Comment: The b2b store is an LWR store